# Backface culling/selection

Tags: modeling

How do I toggle between backface selection and camera based selection? I mean when I'm in edit mode if I drag-box-select I can only select faces that are facing the camera. I know that if I switch to wireframe I can select everything at once. But I almost never need camera based selection, it's useless to me. So I want to be able to disable camera based selection and not have to switch to wireframe every time. Usually in other software there is a checkbox somewhere for this, but I can't find it in Blender.

So far this has been my biggest issue. Any ideas?

Comment: This "checkbox" is next to wireframe mode button (left side).

Comment: @vklidu can you please tell me what it's called? or send me a documentation link or something? I can't find it. The wireframe button is up right corner next to other shading mods and an I can't find the option there. Thanks